# Стили с определенной высоты

Tags: css

Всем привет! Возможно ли так? Ну например, фиксированное меню изначально имеет прозрачность по умолчанию, далее как посетитель начнет пролистывать вниз, сработал на какой-то высоте стиль `opacity: 0.6;`, ну и естественно при наведении по умолчанию. Вообщем, как это прописать в `css`. Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: При наведении можно вернуть через css (:hover), а вот при прокрутке надо через js делать. Теперь главный вопрос - что вы пробовали сами и что не получилось?

Comment: Через js знаю как, сделал. Хотелось бы, если можно через css лучше. JS у меня не поддерживает IE8. Для восьмерки обязательно.

Comment: скролл через css не бывает, показывайте как именно сделал через js и что именно не работает.

восьмерка не поддерживает половину html5 зачем ее вообще держать, я еще понимаю 7ку, из-за того что 8-10ка не встает на XP но 8ку то зачем ? особенно когда дело касается рюшечек.

Comment: @eicto, я тебя вообще не понял. Зачем ты пишешь про 7-ку, кому она нужна тогда, когда ты говоришь про 8-ку так. Вот тут http://jsfiddle.net/g9u8G/2/. Начинаю пролистывать вниз все норм, в исходное положение и текст прыгает под меню. Ну вот здесь на js, конечно, я ошибся с выше сказанным, что у меня получилось реализовать стиль при определенной высоте, хотелось бы сделать это.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/g9u8G/4/

еще раз поясню свою позицию, 7ка и даже 6ка бывает необходима в силу независящих от юзера причин, а у 8ки таких причин нет.

Comment: @eicto, Спасибо большое за помощь! То, что надо.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g9u8G/5/